# Why can't I use QString::arg function here?

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

You know that everywhere you need a QString object as a parameter you can use just c style strings . For example `showMessage` function needs QString. But I passed a C-style string to this function and every thing is OK. I mean here we can think of  `"%1 a sample text"` as a QString object! maybe!

```
statusBar()->showMessage("%1 a sample text");
```

But why can't we use this code:

```
statusBar()->showMessage("%1 a sample text".arg("This is "));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `implicit-conversion` to `QString` will be used, when passed `const char[]` to function and there is no `implicit-conversion`, without call to function, so, you are trying to call method `arg` on `const char[]`, that is incorrect, construct `QString` by

```
statusBar()->showMessage(QString("%1 a sample text").arg("This is "));
```

and all will be fine.

Comment: If this code is part of the class that inherits QObject, then you can write less symbols using QObject::tr() method. tr("%1 a sample text").arg("This is ")

Answer (score 1):

Anything in the form of `"..."` is of the type `const char*`, and thus not a `QString`. This is a side effect of C++ having to be compatible with C.

However, in certain situations (e.g. `operator+`), implicit conversion to `QString` is allowed, as `QString` has a constructor taking a parameter of the type `const char*`. In this case, however, you need to use explicit conversion, i.e.

```
statusBar()->showMessage(QString("%1 a sample text").arg("This is "));
```